# Kendo Grid.dataItem loop not working

Tags: javascript, loops, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, dataitem

So my aim it to loop through all selected item in my kendo grid, but after the first iteration the dataItem method returns undefined.

```
function myFunction() {
var selectedItem = $("#DropDown").val();
var grid = $("#Grid").getKendoGrid();
var selectedItems = grid.select();
for (var i = 0; i < selectedItems.length; i++) {
    var dataItem = grid.dataItem(selectedItems[i]);
    if (dataItem != undefined)
        dataItem.set("Item", SelectedItem);
}
}
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because `set()` performs a grid refresh behind-the-scenes so the DOM is recreated. The array you had with the selected items is lost. You can't rely on the `tr`'s references. As a suggestion I think you can use they indexes instead:

```
function myFunction() {
    var selectedItem = $("#DropDown").val();
    var grid = $("#Grid").getKendoGrid();
    var selectedItems = grid.select().toArray().map((item) => { return $(item).index(); });

    for (var i = 0; i < selectedItems.length; i++) {
        var currentItem = grid.tbody.find(`tr:eq(${selectedItems[i]})`);
        var dataItem = grid.dataItem(currentItem );
        if (dataItem != undefined)
            dataItem.set("Item", SelectedItem);
    }
}
```

- `var selectedItems = grid.select().toArray().map((item) => { return $(item).index(); });`

  This line gets an array of indexes from the selected grid rows to iterate further ahead;
- `` var currentItem = grid.tbody.find(`tr:eq(${selectedItems[i]})`); ``

  This line retrieves the selected row from by the index.

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@marcio/AyONOlET)

Comment: Your solution did work and was valid, however I used your explanation to solve it slightly differently. I created an array called dataItems and pushed each dataItem in it, then looped through that. I know this involves using more lines but I think its easier to see whats going on.

Comment: @GeorgeB indeed can be even better than what I proposed! Well done!